# How to retrieve all data blocks from database at a certain entry in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am very sorry for this newbie question...
I have data stored in the database (mysql) as tuples.
These data look like **(datetime, frequency, current)** ... etc.

How to retrieve all data from database at a certain time?
for example, I want to get all the saved data at "2015-9-9 8:23:10"

Comment: show your model also

Answer (score 0):

can you show your model.

You can add created and updated fields to your model and query them to retrieve your data

```
class Test(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        default=django.utils.timezone.now, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(
        default=django.utils.timezone.now, blank=True)
```

you can query the Test model then using the time you want

```
Test.objects.all(created=datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

If `datetime field` is the date the data is created, you can do:

`Test.objects.all(datetime__gte=timezone.now)`